# Umbraco : displaying an image using the XSLT

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I'm pretty new to umbraco but found the system pretty easy to use and have done alot in a short space of time. One difficulty I have come accross is displaying an image.

In the document type I have added an "upload" where an image is selected.
In my XSLT I loop through the pages, this loop displays the other fields such as description or title. I am trying to display the image here.

Here is my XSLT for displaying my image, this displays nothing. The field "promothumbImage" is defined in the document type, as I said everything else is working fine.

```
<xsl:value-of select="promothumbImage"/>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to where I am going wrong?

EDIT:

promothumbimage is defined in the document of type "upload"

My XSLT:

```
<!-- The fun starts here -->
<div class="promoitems">

  <xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source)/* [@isDoc and
 string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']"> 
  <div class="promoitem">

<a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
  <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
</a>

<div class="promosmalldesc"> 
  <xsl:value-of select="promoSmallDesc"/>
</div>

<xsl:copy-of select="promothumbImage/*"/> 


  </div>

 </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: What is `promothumbImage`? Show us your XML document.

Comment: @Dimitre: promothumbimage is defined in the document of type "upload"

Comment: Funky, the BIG problem with your question is that you have forgotten to show to us the XML document on which the transformation is applied. Please, provide a complete (but as small as possible) source XML document, a complete XSLT transformation code and the required result from the transformation -- then people will be able to help promptly. Without this information we are forced to *guess* what elements as `promothumbImage` actually contain. There is no guarantee at all such guessing is going to be correct ever and this is not a weather forecast forum.

Comment: funny that, i've put the exact same question on the umbraco forum and I've already got the answer! hmmmm

Answer (score 1):

**Upload** means that the element promothumbImage returns the URL of the image, thus the following should display it on the page:

```
<img src="{promothumbImage}" alt=""/>
```

Comment: thanks, I tried that but it renders nothing. Is it because it is inside the loop?

Comment: no, $currentPage/promothumbImage should work inside a loop. Can you do <textarea><xsl:copy-of select="$currentPage"/></textarea> and paste the result in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, use:

```
<img src="{promothumImage}" />
```

to display the image from the "upload" set in the document type

Comment: aha, but since you're looping through other documents promothumImage is not part of $currentPage, which you never said :)

Answer (score 0):

use may simply in your template using your image field throght Media picker Data Type:

```
<img class="className" src='<umbraco:Item field="infoGraphic" runat="server" Xslt="umbraco.library:GetMedia({0},false())/umbracoFile"/>'/>
```